# Vertical spacing in ToC in scrbook with multiple parts

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook

I am writing a scrbook with two parts, two appendices and a bibliography. I would like to add vertical space in toc after Part II so that the section of toc where the appendices are becomes visually separated from Part II. How can I achieve this?

I might also want to add vertical space in toc between the last appendix and the bibliography.

A solution would be to put the appendices in their own part. However, I am not really sure that it is customary to do; I think of parts as of blocks  distinguishing different topics but the appendices may contain bits of everything; there is no new topic "appendices". Or?

This is what I have so far and want to modify it.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@misc{A,
  author = {A.A.},
  year = {2019},
  title = {A},
}
@misc{B,
  author = {B.B.},
  year = {2019},
  title = {B},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

    \tableofcontents

\mainmatter

        \chapter{Introduction}
    \part{Part I}
        \chapter{Chapter A}
            \cite{A}
        \chapter{Chapter B}
            \cite{B}
    \part{Part II}
        \chapter{Chapter C}
        \chapter{Chapter D}

\appendix

    \chapter{Appendix A}
    \chapter{Appendix B}

\backmatter

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add spacing in the table of contents with code such as:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{10pt}}%
```

For your document:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@misc{A,
  author = {A.A.},
  year = {2019},
  title = {A},
}
@misc{B,
  author = {B.B.},
  year = {2019},
  title = {B},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\part{Part I}
\chapter{Chapter A}
\cite{A}
\chapter{Chapter B}
\cite{B}
\part{Part II}
\chapter{Chapter C}
\chapter{Chapter D}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{10pt}}%
\appendix

\chapter{Appendix A}
\chapter{Appendix B}

\backmatter

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{10pt}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Great, thank you very much!